# Element-wise differentiation of a unit-normalized vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors, normed-spaces

Let $f_d$ is the $d^{th}$ element of a $D$-dimensional vector $\mathbf{f}$.
SImilarly, $\hat{f_d}$ is the $d^{th}$ element of its unit normalized form: $\hat{\mathbf{f}} = \frac{\mathbf{f}}{||\mathbf{f}||}$.

I wanted to compute $\frac{\partial \hat{f_d}}{\partial f_d}$ and found:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \hat{f_d}}{\partial f_d} = \frac{1 - \hat{f_d^2}}{||\mathbf{f}||}
\end{equation}

However, this [**paper**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06890.pdf) (in **Page 4**, **Eq. 9**) provides the following form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \hat{f_d}}{\partial f_d} = \frac{1 - (\mathbf{\hat{f}}^T . \bigtriangledown \mathbf{\hat{f}}) \hat{f_d}}{||\mathbf{f}||}
\end{equation}

Can anyone please help me to find what did I miss?

Thanks.

Comment: The paper doesn't show your issue with the problem, in fact it actually agrees with your first step. I'm not sure where you got that other form from

Comment: Thank you @Triatticus. In fact, the paper has changed its formulation and provided the modified form in Eq. 8 (page 4).

Answer (score 9):

Let $s$ denote the length of the vector, and note that 
$$\eqalign{
 s^2 &= f^Tf \cr
s\,ds &= f^Tdf \cr
}$$
Let's denote the unit vector as $n$ and then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 n &= \frac{f}{s} \cr\cr
dn &= \frac{s\,df-f\,ds}{s^2} \cr
   &= \frac{s^2I\,df-ff^Tdf}{s^3} \cr
   &= \frac{1}{s}\Big(I-nn^T\Big)\,df \cr\cr
\frac{\partial n}{\partial f} &= \frac{1}{s}\Big(I-nn^T\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
Extracting the $(k,k)$ element of this matrix is 
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial n_k}{\partial f_k}
  &= \frac{1}{s}\Big(I_{kk}-n_kn_k^T\Big) \cr
  &= \frac{1}{\|f\|}\Big(1-n_k^2\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
So your result looks correct to me.